# mobile view for article doesn't work

Tags: css

I'm trying to add mobile view for this page. I want article and div.sidebar.col-md-4 to be on left on mobile view (sidebar above article). Here's link to the page:https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Press/#mm-0

Here's my code

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
div.sidebar.col-md-4 {
    float: right !important;
        width: 162px !important;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    div.sidebar.col-md-4 {
float: right !important;
        width: 162px !important;

    }
    article{width:50% !important;
    float:left !important;}
}


div.profile p{
text-align: justify;

}
div.profile p a{
float:right;

}
div.profile ul{

  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
h3.name{
  margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}
article{
    width: 50% !important;
    float:left !important;}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
div.sidebar.col-md-4{
  float:right;
  width:162px;
}
div.profile img{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
img.arch{
  width:120px !important;
  height:100px !important;
      margin-top: 18px !important;
      float: left !important;
margin-right: 9px !important;
}
div#disqus_thread{
  float:left;
      width: 523px;
}
```

What happens when I add media query for 768px the article appears below left side menu which I don't want. How to add mobile view without resetting 1200px view?

Any advice much appreciated,
Kind regards 
Neko

Comment: to be precise when I add code @media (min-width:768px){article{clear:left;width:100%;}} the view for 1200 displays not correct as if this code reset the 1200 view

Comment: Can you give an image of what you want to achieve here?

Comment: http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/mymap/press.png

Comment: How to achieve this layout @Hopper?

Comment: Just don't apply float: right for @media (min-width:768px) and set the article width to 100%.

Comment: I didn't for @media (min-width:768px) I applied: {article{clear:left;width:100%;}}  Where do you see float:right?

Comment: Sorry, i meant don't apply this for width less than 768px

Answer (score 0):

```
div.sidebar.col-md-4{
  float:right;
  width:162px;
}
```

Move this inside @media (min-width:768px), and just define another style for width <= 768px

Comment: I did as you suggested and unfortunately the article moved underneath left side menu leaving a gap in the middle column. How to fix it? Here's link: https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Press/

Comment: remove the clear:left; for @media (min-width: 600px)

Comment: I removed clear:left but then article and div.sidebar.col-md-4 are  in 2 columns next to each other in the mobile view. I need them to be one above other like in this picture http://ewelinawoloszyn.com/mymap/press.png

Comment: Did you remove the float right? Also, don't forget to set the article width to 100%

Comment: So my code looks like this: '@media (min-width: 768px){
div.sidebar.col-md-4{
  float:right;
  width:162px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 600px){
div.sidebar.col-md-4{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
    article{
    
    width:100%;    
    }    
    
}'

Comment: Use @media(max-width: 768px) { div.sidebar.col-md-4{ div.sidebar.col-md-4{ float:left; width:100%; } article{ width:100%; }  }. Use !important if other styles are overlapping. Although float:left is pointless with 100% width

Comment: I've removed article{} and div.sidebar.col-md-4{} from code without media query and the layout works now. Thank you for your help @Hopper